# Type-hint for sklearn BaseEstimator

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am working on ML project. I am using `sklearn` library. I am writing a custom transformer to remove duplicate rows from dataframe as below:

```
class RemoveDuplicateRows(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """Custom transformer for remove duplicate rows."""

    # def __init__(self) -> None:
    #    """Initialize the defaults."""
    #    self._count: int = 0

    def fit(self, X: pd.DataFrame, y: pd.Series = None) -> Self:
        """Learn the parameters."""
        return self

    def transform(self, X: pd.DataFrame, y: pd.Series = None) -> pd.DataFrame:
        """Transform the input."""
        return X.drop_duplicates()
```

I am able to run inside a `pipeline` (without type-hints). Upon successfull run, now I have type-hinted it and getting error as below:

```
error: Class cannot subclass "BaseEstimator" (has type "Any")  [misc]
error: Class cannot subclass "TransformerMixin" (has type "Any")  [misc]
```

What I am missing?